# WPF prevent TextBlock from showing multiple lines without setting the height-property

Tags: wpf

I have a textblock within a GridView that is bound to a property that contains sometimes carriage returns in the text. How can I prevent the text-block showing more than one line of text? The only solution I have found is to set the height-property but this seems to me very unproper.

I expected the following declaration to do the trick, but it does not run. Maybe I have something forgotten?

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Info" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Info}"/>                                            
        </DataTemplate>                                    
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to check the string for CR's before binding it to the TextBlock. Strip any \r and \n from the text.

Comment: +1 You mean writing a value converter or add a special property to the data source to filter the CR's out? This is in deed a possibility, but is there no xaml-only-way?